# How to set feature vertex Z from an intersecting feature's Z?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, 3d

In ArcGIS how can I set the Z values of the portion of a line that intersects another line to the Z values from the other line? A batch process is preferred.

I tried [FeatureToLine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000039000000), but the null values of line A (blue) remain null.

*[update]* The red line is source and has a constant Z, though ultimately there is no reason it has to be constant. Blue line is variable Z, the target, the one with vertices we want to change, while the red line should be read-only and unaltered by the operation.

[image: a 620m line crossing a 0m line]

(The diamonds are just to indicate where the vertices are.)

Comment: do input and output lines have the constant Z ?

Comment: @radouxju red line has constant Z, blue line does not. Red line should be read-only and unaltered by the operation.

Comment: Is there always a vertex at the intersection of the two lines?

Comment: @Hornbydd, not at present but I can ensure there is if that's necessary or makes it easier.

Comment: So not only do you want to get the Z value from the red line you also want to edit the geometry of the blue line by inserting a vertex and assigning it's Z value?

Comment: @Hornbydd yes. I want to assign blue Z at the point of intersection to equal red Z.

Comment: here are my incomplete attempts to resolve this: https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/commit/be57d8d7d06565133dda185da177957b82c56058. This part of the overall project has gone dormant, so I won't be following up for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Integrate tool to insert a vertex at the intersection the two lines. Just make sure your contour dataset has a lower rank and your blue line datasets is Z aware. The Integrate tool does not honour the Z value (I checked this on some sample data) so you would then need to update the Z property of the inserted vertex. Now at this point I'm unaware of any existing geo-processing tool that can take a height value *in a field* and use that to update the Z property of a vertex...

I suspect you need to be using some ArcObjects to achieve this next step. Some code is discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50082/arcobjects-update-geometry-z-values-of-line-vertices-with-a-given-number).

Comment: Thanks for *Integrate*. I didn't like how *FeatureToLine* moves vertices unpredictably and breaks things into smaller pieces. I've been given the "time to move on!" signal from supervisor so won't be following up on the arcobjects portion right now. This part of the bigger project has been put to sleep. :-/

Answer (score 0):

[Z Vertex Transfer From Attributes Table in ArcGIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vZ48MkEyRs)
This video you shown two way Z-Vertex value transferred from attributes value

Comment: Please, don't post a link-only answer, provide some details of the process. Video can be deleted in a future, so it's important to post a complete answer to this problem.